# AngularJS and NodeJS app in Docker

Tags: angularjs, node.js, docker

I have an angular and nodejs app.
The API's (nodejs) is running on port 8888
The Angular is running on port 8080

Now the app is running in a docker container.
The container is running by:

```
docker run -d -p 49160:8080 --name app localhost:5000/test/app
```

The problem is. Now I'm able to visiting the API's on localhost:49160 but I don't know how to access my angular. Which is running on another port

Do I need 2 containers? In each tutorial I see it in the same container.

EDIT: this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g bower
RUN npm install -g gulp

# Install app dependencies
COPY . /usr/src/app/
RUN bower install
RUN npm install
RUN gulp build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

My run command is:

```
docker run -d -p 49160:8080 -p 8888:8888 --name app localhost:5000/test/app
```

My angular is running on port 8080 and nodejs on 8888.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can expose multiple ports of your Docker container by repeating the `-p` flag:

```
docker run -p <host_port1>:<container_port1> -p <host_port2>:<container_port2>
```

In your case you could do:

```
docker run -d -p 49160:8080 -p 8888:8888 --name app localhost:5000/test/app
```

Comment: I've exposed the ports, didn't know that it was possible but still I can't see my angular.

Comment: Are you sure Angular is running on the expected port? You can use `docker run -i -t -p 49160:8080 -p 8888:8888 localhost:5000/test/app /bin/bash` to start it up and login to a terminal.